# Set a custom class as an optional argument's type to a method within that class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, args, optional-arguments

tl;dr:
I want to know how to set an optional argument's type to a custom built class, i.e;

Code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x=int,y=int):   # Initialize Point object with optional args
        self.val=(x,y)
    def __add__(self,p=Point):        # p=Point is the issue
        ...
```

I've tried:

```
def __add__(self,p=self.__class__):  # Cannot reference self in an arg.
def __add__(self,p=Point):           # Point is not defined
```

Long story:

I've done several searches that found nothing so far, but I think its more the terms I'm using.

I'm building a 2d Point/Vector class (I know, been done already, but I'm learning, and developing my writing style.), and I've developed an aversion to using untyped positional args in most cases, mainly for ease of maintenance.

I haven't been able to figure out how to set an optional arg's type to a custom built class, such as Point above, instead of one of python's built in types.

Note: I'm aware that simply making p a positional arg would work, and it does, but as long as there is no main reason not to do things this way, other than it being slightly rigid for python's philosophy, I'd like to type the args for clarity of code.

How can that be accomplished, is it worth it, and are there any cons to doing things this way?

Any tips on best practices for this type of thing are greatly welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding what `x=int` and `y=int` are doing in your code.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x=int,y=int):   # Initialize Point object with optional args
    ...
    def __add__(self,p=Point):
```

Creating an instance of `Point`,

```
u = Point()
```

would produce an object `u`.  The optional arguments `x` and `y` will be equal to the Python object that represents the `int` `type` not integers (here distinguish between integers like 1, 3, 99 and their type=int). In general, using the equals sign in function arguments specifies a default value not a type.  Likewise, if the argument `p` is not passed to the function `add`, `p` will be equal to the object that represent the class `Point`.  It will not make `p` an instance of the class `Point`.  You cannot specify in advance the type of function arguments.  In addition their types can be changed inside the function.  This is because Python is a dynamically typed language.

This [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) on duck typing might help clarify things.  If you like, you can check the type of the arguments after they are passed in and act on that information, but the basic idea is, if it walks like an `int` and talks like an `int`, who cares if its actual type is `int`.

The Python section of the duck typing article leads to a description of [exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) in Python and their suggested use in these situations.

Comment: It's Python 2.7, too, so there aren't any [function annotations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which sometimes *are* used to indicate argument types and look kind of similar to default argument values.

Comment: Ok, that clears up one question, I always assumed that by declaring x=int that it would require an int type object instead of passing x as a type name. I'm not looking for statically typed functionality, more of a note to remind myself or anyone who reads my code which arg SHOULD be what type, rather than a declaration that it HAS to be that type.

Comment: @Eevee, Good point! The class is well documented, I was just wondering if there was still some static type support, for extra reinforcements in a couple of areas to avoid (human) errors without explicitly checking types within the function.

Comment: also probably worth taking a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) search for EAFP for the "pythonic" philosophy.

Comment: @Gabriel, thanks for the link, I'm a strong believer in python's philosophy, but some of the people I work with are not, I'm trying to convert them... Eh hem. Accomodate them somewhat.

Comment: you got it, happy pythoning :)

Answer (score 2):

Gabriel's answer is correct, and this is probably not what you want.

But regarding the actual symptom you're seeing: it has nothing to do with built-in vs custom types.  The problem is that default arguments are evaluated as soon as the function is defined, but a class doesn't exist until *after* the end of the class body.  So you can't use `Point` as a default argument inside its own class body, because at that point in execution, `Point` doesn't exist yet!

Comment: Well that rules out my next try of decorating the method with @classmethod and passing cls instead of self. However, if the class isn't actually created until its final method is defined, the same thing will happen. Funny enough, you answered another question I had a few months ago about when a class is actually created, thank you!

Comment: it's because the class is created by calling the `type()` constructor, and one of its arguments is a dict of stuff that should be in the class dict, and you don't have that until the end of the class body  :)

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd subclass tuple to do this:

```
>>> class Point(tuple):
...     def __new__ (cls, x, y):
...         return super(Point, cls).__new__(cls, (x,y))
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         super(Point, self).__init__(x,y)
...         self.x=int(x)
...         self.y=int(y)
...     def __add__(self,point_add):
...         if len(point_add) != 2:
...             exit("Not a coordinate")
...         new_x = self.x + int(point_add[0])
...         new_y = self.y + int(point_add[1])
...         new_point = self.__new__(Point, new_x, new_y)
...         new_point.x = new_x
...         new_point.y = new_y
...         return new_point
... 
>>> p_a = Point(1, 2)
>>> p_b = Point(1, 2)
>>> p_c = p_a + p_b
>>> print "tuple:", p_c
tuple: (2, 4)
>>> print "x:", p_c.x, "y:", p_c.y
x: 2 y: 4
>>>
```

This will allow you to treat points as tuples and to an extent tuples as points. The `__add__()` method above works for adding either a tuple or a Point.

Comment: Thats pretty much what my code looks like, minus a few lines, and minus the inheritance, and separate variables. One question though, why subclass tuple and store separate values x and y, instead of subclassing object which, correct me if I'm wrong, being the most base object, should have the lowest memory overhead overall, and just storing both values in a single variable tuple? As a side note, I subclassed object, and wrote a __getitem__ so Point['x'] and Point[0] both returned the first value of tuple Point.val, is dot notation a faster way to reference?

Comment: @WeRelic the x and y attributes are only eye candy. You could just use self[0] and self[1] but I thought I'd demonstrate that you can use x and y attributes if you want more clarity. As for which is faster I'm not sure. The idea behind subclassing tuple is that it would allow you to treat a Point abject as if it were a tuple which could be useful given that a lot of functions that handle 2d vectors and coordinates will expect tuples. Eg pygame's functions for creating surfaces.